# Reset local area connection

Tags: windows-7, command-line, internet, internet-connection

My internet connection gets disconnected sometimes so I click on Troubleshoot problems in Windows 7 and it gets fixed when the troubleshooter resets the Local area connection.

The problem is that it takes sometime for it to reset and verify that the issue has been fixed,so I'm wondering if there's a Command which automatically does that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Disable:

netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLED

You can create .bat script.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

`ipconfig /release` followed by `ipconfig /renew`

Comment: Yea I know that,but it's like the connection gets back for some seconds and disconnects again. only way it gets fixed properly is when I click troubleshoot problems.